# How to count messages received with Python

Tags: python, global-variables, counter, bots, chatroom

I've been using the code tutorial [found here](https://www.sinister.ly/Thread-Tutorial-Chatango-Bot-Tutorial) to make a bot for a Chatango chat room. My basic code is as follows:

```
import ch
import random
import sys

class bot(ch.RoomManager):

  def onInit(self):
    self.setNameColor("000000")
    self.setFontColor("000000")
    self.setFontFace("Ariel")
    self.setFontSize(11)

  def onMessage(self, room, user, message):

    print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))

    try:
      cmd, args = message.body.split(" ", 1)
    except:
      cmd, args = message.body, ""

    if cmd[0] == "!":
      prfx = True
      cmd = cmd[1:]
    else:
      prfx = False

rooms = ["room0", "room1"]
username = "username goes here"
password = "password goes here"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

It's basically what you see on the website I linked above. Having used it the past few days, I know the code works. What I am trying to implement is a method of counting messages as they come in. I have already tried something along the lines of:

```
import ch
import random
import sys

class bot(ch.RoomManager):

  count = 0

  def onInit(self):
    self.setNameColor("000000")
    self.setFontColor("000000")
    self.setFontFace("Ariel")
    self.setFontSize(11)

  def onMessage(self, room, user, message):

    print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))

    global count
    count = count + 1
    print (count)

    try:
      cmd, args = message.body.split(" ", 1)
    except:
      cmd, args = message.body, ""

    if cmd[0] == "!":
      prfx = True
      cmd = cmd[1:]
    else:
      prfx = False

rooms = ["room0", "room1"]
username = "username goes here"
password = "password goes here"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

I am new to Python, but I can't seem to figure out why this wouldn't print out a proper count every time someone sends a message. How can I make this counter work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count is member of class object "bot", If u intend to use count declared inside class body then access it as bot.count.
I don't see any global count which you are trying to use.

Comment: Should I declare ``count`` outside of the class then? Would that make it global?

Comment: If you want to use global count then yes, declare it outside class. 
If you want to use count as member of class then use bot.count.
But I would suggest to design it properly, decide If u need a global count, class object's count or instance object's count

Comment: I implemented this idea and it has accomplished my goal. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have ch.RoomManager (and an account), I cannot test it. Global variable should work as well:

```
import ch
import random
import sys

# Initiate count
count = 0

class bot(ch.RoomManager):
    def onInit(self):
        self.setNameColor("000000")
        self.setFontColor("000000")
        self.setFontFace("Ariel")
        self.setFontSize(11)

      def onMessage(self, room, user, message):

        print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))

        global count
        count = count + 1
        print (count)

        try:
          cmd, args = message.body.split(" ", 1)
        except:
          cmd, args = message.body, ""

        if cmd[0] == "!":
          prfx = True
          cmd = cmd[1:]
        else:
          prfx = False

rooms = ["room0", "room1"]
username = "username goes here"
password = "password goes here"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but when I try this, my program crashes on me. Unfortunately, it crashes too quickly for me to see what error it throws.

Comment: The self.count is also possible, but you need to make a `def __init__(self): self.count = 0`. [This tutorial](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html) may help you with using this class variable version.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Create a file named "log.txt" and copy the following:

```
import ch
import random
import sys

class bot(ch.RoomManager):
    def onInit(self):
        self.setNameColor("000000")
        self.setFontColor("000000")
        self.setFontFace("Arial")
        self.setFontSize(11)

    def onMessage(self, room, user, message):
        f = open("log.txt", "a") # "a" means append/add
        f.write("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body)+"\n")
        f.close()

        print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(room.name, user.name.title(), message.body))

        try:
            cmd, args = message.body.split(" ", 1)
        except:
            cmd, args = message.body, ""

        if len(cmd) > 0:
            if cmd[0] == "!":
                prfx = True
                cmd = cmd[1:]
            else:
                prfx = False
        else:
            return

        if cmd == "say" and prfx:
            if args: room.message(args)
            else: room.message("Nothing to say!")

        elif cmd == "count" and prfx:
            room.message("Numbers of messages sent in all rooms I am in: "+str(len(open("log.txt").readlines())))

rooms = ["room0", "room1"]
username = "username goes here"
password = "password goes here"

bot.easy_start(rooms,username,password)
```

I fixed some stuffs that happen to crash when I used the code before. I am not using that anymore though. And on the command, it is all rooms! Not just one room, okay?